# Need to read an https web page but my web server dont support https wrapper

Tags: php, curl, https

i need to read the content of a web page using php with this simple command:

```
$pagina='https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' . $cookie['access_token'];
$user = json_decode(file_get_contents($pagina));
```

As you can see the protocol is https. When i execute this commands i always get:

> [function.file-get-contents]: failed
>   to open stream:

In other answer in stackoverflow some user suggest to use this code:

```
$w = stream_get_wrappers();
echo 'openssl: ',  extension_loaded  ('openssl') ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'http wrapper: ', in_array('http', $w) ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'https wrapper: ', in_array('https', $w) ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'wrappers: ', var_dump($w);
```

In order to know if my server have https wrapper, and the result was No.

So, any idea of how can i retrive this https page using php? maybe with CURL any example code? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Https sites work with curl

```
<?php
$url = "https://www.google.com/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: the result is empty... and with vardump bool(false)

Comment: run this code after curl_exec -> echo curl_error($ch); to see the error message